# How to apply formatting to string as shown in below question?

Tags: python

I am trying to set the output formatting but not getting the relevant code portion.

The task:

> Given an integer, , print the following values for each integer  from  to :
>
> - Decimal
> - Octal
> - Hexadecimal (capitalized)
> - Binary
> - Function Description
>
> Complete the `print_formatted` function in the editor below.
>
> `print_formatted` has the following parameters:
>
> - `int number`: the maximum value to print
>
> Prints
>
> The four values must be printed on a single line in the order specified above for each  from  to . Each value should be space-padded to match the width of the binary value of  and the values should be separated by a single space.
>
> Input Format
>
> A single integer denoting .
>
> Constraints
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 17
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
>     1     1     1     1
>     2     2     2    10
>     3     3     3    11
>     4     4     4   100
>     5     5     5   101
>     6     6     6   110
>     7     7     7   111
>     8    10     8  1000
>     9    11     9  1001
>    10    12     A  1010
>    11    13     B  1011
>    12    14     C  1100
>    13    15     D  1101
>    14    16     E  1110
>    15    17     F  1111
>    16    20    10 10000
>    17    21    11 10001
> ```

Below is the code I wrote in python:

```
def print_formatted(number):
    # your code goes here
    for n in range(1, number+1):
        print(n, str(oct(n))[2:].upper(), str(hex(n))[2:].upper(), str(bin(n))[2:].upper(), sep=" ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```

It is working but formatting is missing and not accepted as solution.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HT6o.png)

Comment: It looks like when you copy-pasted the task, some math notation went missing. Here for example: `integer, , print the following values for each integer from  to :` It looks like that should be something like ``integer, `number`, print the following values for each integer from `1` to `number+1`:``

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding in formatting syntax *(Check: [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec))*

```py
def print_formatted(number):
    formats = "doXb"  # d - decimal, o - octal, X - hexadecimal, b - binary
    padding = number.bit_length()  # length of number in binary
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        for fmt in formats:
            print(f"{i:{padding}{fmt}}", end=" ")
        print()  # new line
```

Usage:

```py
print_formatted(17)
```

Output:

```
    1     1     1     1 
    2     2     2    10 
    3     3     3    11 
    4     4     4   100 
    5     5     5   101 
    6     6     6   110 
    7     7     7   111 
    8    10     8  1000 
    9    11     9  1001 
   10    12     A  1010 
   11    13     B  1011 
   12    14     C  1100 
   13    15     D  1101 
   14    16     E  1110 
   15    17     F  1111 
   16    20    10 10000 
   17    21    11 10001
```